# Validate polymorphic votes - Controller or Model?

Tags: php, architecture, mvc, laravel

I have a question because I don't want to do something wrong.

I have a polymorphic relation called votes. Well, I want to save votes but I need to validate if a user already has voted. But even if, in some cases a user can vote multiple times. It depends on the type (as said, polymorphic relation). I've set this data in a config file.

Now, where should I validate the votes? I thought I could do it in the model with a static method but then I'd be retrieving the config files in the model and also I'd have to return multiple errors. Something like *"you have already voted"* or *"you can vote again in 1 hour"*.

I'd do that with some kind of error codes which I'd pass to the controller and then to the view to inform the user. But it seems wrong to me.

What would be the right way of doing this?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "right" and "wrong."

Comment: Thanks, I mean the right mvc way. I'm using laravel as framework by the way.

Comment: By what criteria do you want us to judge the "right" MVC way?  There is seldom "the one right way" in software development. Rather, there are ways that are "better" or "worse" in some way, such as performance, maintainability, ease of use, ease of development, resistance to obsolescence, and so forth.  Tell us the ways that you want us to apply here.

Comment: Have you read this yet?  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation

Comment: I think maintainability fits well. I just thought controllers should be as slim as possible. So personally I'd do it in the model. My concern are the error codes. I'd still need to check which error occurred in the controller to inform the view (with JSON). I could do it with multiple function calls on the model as well - like hasVotedAlready(), if true then canVoteAgain() but this would eventually cause more database queries (performance).

Comment: Yes I've read that but I don't want to validate things like minimum length of a string or something. It's a more specific thing where I need to validate with my own rules that I get from my config file and therefore I need to retrieve entries from the votes table.

Comment: Rule of thumb: *favor fat models and thin controllers.*  I generally put the validation logic somewhere in the model, as in `DomainObject.IsValid()` and `DomainObject.GetValidationErrors()`.  Does Laravel has a mechanism for returning collections of errors to the View?

Comment: Yes, thought the same. Do you mean returning error collections (as array?) from within a model? You could return an array to the controller and pass it to the view if that's what you're thinking about.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Yes of course you could collect errors and add them to an array which you then pass to the controller. The controller itself could pass them to a view. Would you do it this way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21132/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-maddin).

Comment: You should trust your own judgment more; your thinking seems reasonably sound. Check Laravel for patterns that do this; the framework almost certainly contains some provision for passing errors back to the user for correction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should validate your models in... model validators ;)

In my current architecture each model has an associated validator class, which contains validation logic. (Controllers have validators as well, but that's not the point). This is because validation logic can sometimes be complex enough, especially when models receive states.

To validate a model I just pass the result of $model->getAttributes() to a validator. The part, responsible for creating a validator and passing it attributes is now a part of my custom BaseModel class.

I've set it up so validation runs when model is saved. If model is invalid, exception is occured. So, the controller or service, saving the model, are responsible for it's validation.

Validation result is empty when validation succeeds or a hash of errors ('fieldName1' => ErrorsArray1). ErrorsArray is a standard Laravel's MessageBag, using which it's easy to render errors to user.

So, to model/controller it doesn't matter if User can't vote at all, or will be able to vote again in 1 hour. Model validator creates an error message (cannot_vote or cannot_vote_tmp) and just bubbles it to controller, which passes it to view. View translates message if needed and presents it to the user.

Currently errors are just enumerated and presented to user using a simple list next to the input field it is related to. But this logic can be extended. If it becomes complex enough, you can place some of it into a ViewComposer, which will take errors from controller, calculate some state from them and then pass this state into a View freeing it from complex calculations.